# youtube-dl and aria2c - batch download based on a list with YouTube links and saving each file according to a list of file names

Tags: youtube-dl

There is some ways of saving files downloaded with youtube-dl, like this:

youtube-dl -o "1-%(uploader)s%(title)s.%(ext)s

What I trying to do is, the same way as I have a URL.TXT containing each YouTube link, line by line, I would like to save the downloaded video files names according to a file name list, line by line.

Example:

URL.TXT

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video3
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video4
```

FILES_NAMES.TXT

```
VIDEO_FILE_NAME1
VIDEO_FILE_NAME2
VIDEO_FILE_NAME3
VIDEO_FILE_NAME4
```

So, in my directory, instead of using YouTube's video name, it would write the downloaded file using my file name's list. Example:

```
VIDEO_FILE_NAME1.MP4
VIDEO_FILE_NAME2.MP4
VIDEO_FILE_NAME3.MP4
VIDEO_FILE_NAME4.MP4
```

I'm using youtube-dl and aria2c for downloading. According to aria2c documentation, it says:

"

```
These options have exactly same meaning of the ones in the command-line options, but it just applies to the URIs it belongs to. Please note that for options in input file -- prefix must be stripped.

For example, the content of uri.txt is:

http://server/file.iso http://mirror/file.iso
  dir=/iso_images
  out=file.img
http://foo/bar
If aria2 is executed with -i uri.txt -d /tmp options, then file.iso is saved as /iso_images/file.img and it is downloaded from http://server/file.iso and http://mirror/file.iso. The file bar is downloaded from http://foo/bar and saved as /tmp/bar.

In some cases, out parameter has no effect. See note of --out option for the restrictions.
```

"

What about this syntax:

.\youtube-dl_2021-04-17.exe --format best --write-all-thumbnails --newline --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "-x 16 -s 10 -k 1M -i URL.TXT" -a .\URL.TXT

Where URL.TXT contains this:

```
https://youtu.be/video1
    out=Video_Filne_Name_01
https://youtu.be/video2
    out=Video_Filne_Name_02
https://youtu.be/video3
    out=Video_Filne_Name_03
https://youtu.be/video4
    out=Video_Filne_Name_04
```

Comment: Old thread and all. Yet, `-a URL.TXT` seems invalid. According to https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#filesystem-options the batch file should only have valid links and comments, and indented parameters (`out=foo`) violates that.